# Stop Safari from opening images when an image is dragged-dropped to the browser

Tags: safari

Sometimes I'm trying to drag and drop an image to file upload box on the web but accidentally drop it on the whole webpage itself. Safari would then go to the image URL in the current tab. I'll have to backspace to go back to the original page. If I'm filling out a form, all of the data would be erased. Is there a way to stop this image drag-drop from opening on a page in Safari?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. To fix this issue, probably give a request to Apple to add some feature (use your creativity to do it) here: https://apple.com/feedback.

Or you can browse the App Store to install plugins to help with it somewhat. And yes, I do understand how frustrating it could be while filling out forms.

One of the only ways is to reach out to Apple or you can download Microsoft Edge or any other browser if you like.

But the answer to the question is a no.

Answer (score 1):

No! Not without any extensions at user level.

I guess this is the default behaviour in all apps that support drag and drop feature. If we are dragging something to a page or app, if there isn't any function to handle that; it'll open the file. For ex: If we drag and drop to onedrive webpage, it'll start uploading.

**This behaviour can be handled by the webpage creator to add a user confirmation before leaving the page.**

Answer (score 1):

It can be pretty disastrous with safari because it will replace the current open page and throw away the current contents, which can be a form (like stackoverflow answer) you are just filling in.  Same for Firefox.

My current workaround is to use Chrome.  It still open the dropped file, but at least it always open the dropped file in a new tab, so it does not destroy the current open page.

[image]